# Highstock - irregular time interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts has an example using irregular time intervals, I want to do the same on highstock howeverthere is no parameter for the xAxis-type.

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/cS6r5/17/)

My options are

```
$(function() {

$.getJSON('http://184.173.195.228/~ktwsn/temp2.php?action=get_sensor&sensor_serial%5B%5D=3B74F41400000069&sensor_serial%5B%5D=3BB2FA14000000E6&sensor_serial%5B%5D=3B91F11400000079&sensor_serial%5B%5D=3BC7F114000000E5&sensor_serial%5B%5D=3BC0F314000000E3&callback=?',
      {action: "get_sensor"},
          function(data) {
              var seriesOptions = [];
              $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                  seriesOptions.push({
                      name: val.name,
                      data: val.samples,
                      marker : {
                          enabled : true,
                          radius : 3
                      }
                  });
              });       
              // create the chart
              chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
                  chart: {
                      renderTo: 'container',
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      type: 'datetime'
                  },
                  rangeSelector: {
                      selected: 4
                  },    
                  series: seriesOptions
              });
          });   
});
```

Comment: Could you recerate issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: I have a dataset on jfiddle jsfiddle.net/cS6r5/14

Answer (score 20):

Found it. The nomenclature between highcharts and highstock are different.

For Hightstock it's

```
xAxis: {       
    ordinal: false
}
```

The company really needs to combine highcharts and highstock.  A single API documentation would be easier to follow.

Comment: this can also be a solution if you get the error:
_'Uncaught Highcharts error #19: www.highcharts.com/errors/19'_
and none of the suggested solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify that the output data is actually using the same time stamp.

Many cases like this include time stamps for the same date, but different times, which will always result in different x axis placement.

(I know that may be an obvious check, but I have seen it many times...)

Comment: The datapoints are within second or two from each other, if you look at the Xaxis in the picture, the time on the tooltip isnt even close to the xaxis value.

Comment: From the image, they seem to range about 20 minutes.
It's hard to tell much more without seeing the data output, or a live example of the chart (throw it up on jsfiddle, or jsbin, perhaps...)

Comment: I have found this property xAxis: {type: 'datetime'} which seems to be for irregular intervals which is exactly what I have but it seems to have no effect.